# I don't understand Error

Tags: ios, objective-c, null

There is a property

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) MyObject* object;
```

I made new object with

```
self.object = [MyObject new];
```

I use it, then try to delete

```
self.object = nil;
```

But I got this

```
0x1533840:  movl   (%eax,%ecx), %ecx
```

Can you explain it to me? thanks :)

Comment: Can you put more code?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17431750/nsstring-conversion-to-lowercase-crashes

Comment: @NitinGohel, your link isn't satisfied questioner requirement.

Comment: That error isn't helpful. You need to provide more details.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your `MyObject` class looks like, but typically you would allocate and initialize an object. Check to see what you're doing in the `new` method. If you want to use your object's `new` method, just be sure it is correct.

Or try this:

`self.object = [[MyObject alloc] init];`

Comment: new is a shortcut for alloc init

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps MyObject has a more complex init method? new is a shortcut for [[MyObject alloc]init] but if the init is not the designated initializer then the object may be insufficiently initialized.